# react component not getting a return from asyncronous method

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm working on a simple application that uses firebase for google sign on authentication. The authentication part works as far as I can because I'm getting a uid for the user. However, when I try to create a firebase database instance, and call createUserDocumentFromAuth and pass it the user that  was created, I don't see the app going to the method in the console-it looks like it hangs. I put a test method in-hitThis- and I get a return from it, but not the other method.

```
firebase.utils.js
    import {initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore, collection,doc, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore';

import {
        getAuth,
        signInWithRedirect,
        signInWithPopup,
        GoogleAuthProvider
    } from 'firebase/auth';


// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyB8FRK9lJ8WFJa5MnCraDBTiJWN3TJCKmg",
    authDomain: "ztm-react-project.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "ztm-react-project",
    storageBucket: "ztm-react-project.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "737539305609",
    appId: "1:737539305609:web:d7a6bd52d7af973f475658"
  };
  
  // Initialize Firebase
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const db = getFirestore(app);
  const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
  provider.setCustomParameters({
    prompt: "select_account"
  });

  export const auth = getAuth();
  export const signInWithGooglePopup = () => signInWithPopup(auth,provider)

  
  export const createUserDocumentFromAuth = async (userAuth) => {
   const userDocRef = doc(db, 'users', userAuth.uid);   
    console.log(userDocRef);
  }

  export const hitThis = () =>{
    console.log('hit this');
  }

   sign-in.component.jsx

    import { signInWithGooglePopup, createUserDocumentFromAuth, hitThis} from '../../utils/firebase/firebase.utils';

const SignIn = () =>{
    hitThis();
    const logGoogleUser = async () => {
        const user = await signInWithGooglePopup();
        createUserDocumentFromAuth(user);
    }
   return(
    <div>
    <h1>Sign In Page</h1>
    <button onClick={logGoogleUser}>Sign in with Google Popup</button>
</div>

   );

   }
   

export default SignIn
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `createUserDocumentFromAuth` function doesn't call any API that writes data, so that'd explain why you don't see any result in the database. To actually write data, call `setDoc` as shown in the documentation on [writing data to a new document reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document).